# How to fix "current transaction is aborted commands ignored"

Tags: sql, groovy

I am trying to get data from the database by using code below. I am pretty sure that the query is correct but I always get this "DatabaseError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block". How can I fix it?

```
Transaction tx;
tx = persistence.getTransaction()
if (tx == null)
    tx = persistence.createTransaction()
def entityManager = persistence.getEntityManager()


dpArray = entityManager.createNativeQuery(dpSelectQuery, DeliveryPoint.class)
        .setParameter('contract', contract)
        .getResultList()
tx.end()
```

Comment: Please provide the full stacktrace, the exact line where error occurs, the full classname of the Transaction.

Comment: And there is nothing here about sql. Seems question about specific framework

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution. I can't say what is the reason of it, but my query returned null primary key until I replaced all "id" with "ID".
There is a topic about it:
https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/305321/